# Testing returned value of component method with value passed through

Tags: reactjs, testing

Hi I'm trying to make a test for a component method that is passed in a number and returns a string. This is my first time writing test in react and I couldn't find any examples of what to do in my situation.

my code

```
import moment from "moment";
import React from 'react';
class ReactPage extends React.Component {
  //some other functions

  //turn number into money (returns string)
  commafyMoney = (money) => {
    return "$"+ money.toFixed(2).replace(/\d(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$&,');
  }

  //return fancy react webpage
  render(){
    return(
      //stuff
    );
  }
}
export default ReactPage;
```

this is my attempt of testing the returned value

```
import {shallow, mount, render, configure} from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import ReactPage from './App';

it('commafyMoney(number)', () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<ReactPage />);
  expect(wrapper.instance().commafyMoney(1234.56)).toEqual("$1,234.56");
});
```

Does anyone know how I can fix this test so it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Option 1: wrapper.instance()

You're missing some of the waffle required to set up enzyme.

```
import React from 'react'; // React must be in scope any time you write jsx.

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() }); // Let enzyme use the adapter.
```

Add these lines after your imports and the test should pass. (Assuming jest is configured properly.)

### Option 2: Don't render the component.

Since the method you're testing does not directly affect the rendering of your component, you can just get an instance of the component without rendering.

```
import ReactPage from './App';

it('commafyMoney(number)', () => {
  const page = new ReactPage;
  expect(page.commafyMoney(1234.56)).toEqual("$1,234.56");
});
```

This raises the question of why is the method defined in the class instead of being a utility function imported from somewhere else. You would preferably move the method to another module where its easier to test.